# Linq to entities subquery

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

How can I write the following subquery in Linq:

```
Context.Set<Process>()
       .Include(...)
       .Where(x => x.Activity.Name.CompareTo(Context.Set<Activity>().Where(a => a.Id == activityId).Select(c => a.Name)) > 0)
       .Take(1);
```

This is a simplifed version of query, WHERE clause only includes the part that is not working. If I change Context.Set().... subquery to a string constant, then the query works. As it is, it gives NotSupportedException

```
LINQ to entities does not recognize method Set<Activity>
```

Comment: What happens if you use your Activities DbSet explicitly: Context.Activities.Where(...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(from p in context.Set<Process>().Include(...)
 from a in context.Set<Activity>()
 where a.Id == activityId
 where p.Activity.Name.CompareTo(a.Name) > 0
 select p).Take(1);
```